# Presto query: UNNEST a column which is of ARRAY type

Tags: sql, presto

I have the following Presto query:

```
select team from my_table
```

The output is:

```
team
-------
[John, Amy]
[David, Mary, Alex]
[Josh, Ann]
```

Then I want to see all the people like:

```
person
----------
John
Amy
David
Mary
Alex
Josh
Ann
```

I try to use UNNEST like:

```
select UNNEST(team) from my_table
```

But got the following syntax error:

```
mismatched input 'unnest'. Expecting: '*', 'ALL', 'DISTINCT', <expression>, <identifier>
```

Any idea what I did wrong? Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think the syntax you want is:

```
select t.team
from my_table cross join
     unnest(team) as t(team)
```

Comment: Docs: https://prestosql.io/docs/current/sql/select.html#unnest